# Question about Jquery UI Sortable, Option Handle

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to use Jquery UI Sortable to implement drag-drop and sortable display. In addition, I want just use a specific area(header) to drag-drop. 
Example:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ handle: 'h2' });
```

The 'handle' option restricts sort start click to the specified element.

Code example here, http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/9BkJ5/

**The problem is, when I moved on 'h2', I want to see a little 'hand' to show this can drag and drop, I guess it could implement directly use Jquery. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("h2").css("cursor", "pointer");   // Hand cursor
$("h2").css("cursor", "move");      // Directional cursor.
```

An update to your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/9BkJ5/15/

Comment: Greg, thank you for you quick reply. Have a nice Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but the answer provided is incomplete. The OP also wanted to restrict the drag&drop start click to a specific area. This can be done using `handle:".portlet-header"`, as the OP suggested on his own. So, updating the JSfiddle given by Greg, it becomes like this: [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BkJ5/135/)